# Divs get enormous height on building with VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js

When I build my VueJS project with `npm run build` the columns of my grid get an enormous height for no reason (I could find) I'm currently searching for like 3 hours already. Even changed settings etc. I think it has something to do with my css.. I hope this question can help. Couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow regarding this issue.

It looks like the height of the divs are the only issue while building..

In this link you can see how it's supposed to be:
http://jmp.sh/IU64imX

On this url you can see what happens: 
http://206.189.5.59/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your `.grid` class has `min-height: 100vh`. Removing this fixes the issue for me.